# Setting visibility of major ticks only working in debug mode

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to set the visibility of the major and minor ticks in matplotlib and I can't get it working.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.linspace(0, 100, 100)
y = np.linspace(0, 200, 100)

ax.plot(x, y)

for i in range(len(ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks())):
    print(i, ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks()[i].get_loc())

    if ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks()[i].get_loc() < 0 or ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks()[i].get_loc() > 50:
        print('Delete Tick')
        ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks()[i].set_visible(False)


plt.show()
```

If I set a breakpoint (in PyCharm) at the for loop, wait a bit and then let the code run to the end, the ticks are set to invisible as expected. If I let the code run without debugging or simply do not set a breakpoint, the ticks are still visible.

Console output with debugging and breakpoint:

```
0 0.0
1 50.0
2 100.0
Delete Tick
3 150.0
Delete Tick
4 200.0
Delete Tick
```

And the console output with normal execution:

```
0 0
1 0
2 0
3 0
4 0
```

And the corresponding figures:
[image]

[image]

Has anyone experienced this odd problem? Am I missing something?

Comment: Well, you are not crazy; I get the same behaviour with matplotlib 1.5.0, python 2.7 (and no pycharm but just good old pdb).

Comment: Thanks for trying. Do you have an idea why this happens?

Comment: Well the ticks don't actually have a non-zero position when you enter the `if` clause, but I guess you already knew that. I have tried forcing a draw with `fig.canvas.draw()` and `fig.canvas.flush_events()` and even `plt.show(block=False)` before entering the loop but none of these seem to change that.

Comment: If you add `print matplotlib.artist.getp(ax.yaxis); print matplotlib.artist.getp(ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks())` before the loop, you see that the tick positions are already initialised as far as the yaxis artist is concerned, but the individual YTick instances are not. The docs say that "ticks are dynamically created as needed (e.g., when panning and zooming)", so that may be the reason. Hence manipulating the tick positions with `ax.set_yticks()` works fine, manipulating the YTick instances does not.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Forcing the canvas to redraw worked for me. E.g.: insert fig.canvas.draw() in front of the for loop. It you post this as an answer I will accept it since it was your idea.